# Does using curly braces go against the "Ruby way"?

Tags: ruby, forms, builder, curly-braces

I've been using Ruby for about two weeks, and I've not been programming for too terribly long, but I'm coming at the language from a C-style background (C++, C#, etc). Anyway - a good friend and mentor of mine was looking at some Ruby that I'd written the other day, and he told me that he'd smack me if he caught me using curly braces in Ruby again.

Well, I just found out about Builder yesterday, via [this About.com article](http://ruby.about.com/od/gems/a/builder.htm), and the example that they have posted uses curly braces. Is there a different way to do this, or do you have to use curly braces with Builder?

This may seem like a minor point, but I'm new to Ruby, and I don't want to let myself develop any bad habits. What do you guys think?

Comment: +1 for a question that's exposed me to views I hadn't seen before.

Comment: I think you need a new friend. Curly braces are perfectly appropriate, and very commonly used in Ruby. As the responses show, you need to do them with some forethought for readability, and understand the binding difference between `{}` and `do/end`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While some people go with "braces for one-liners, do-end for multi-liners", I personally find the following rule the most logical:

- use `do-end` when your block has side-effects (typically, with `each` and related methods) and
- use braces when your block is without side-effects (`map`, `inject` and alike)

This logic goes well with method chaining issue that Matt wrote about.

One benefit of this approach is that it is going to make you think about side-effects every time you write a block, and they are very important, although sometimes overlooked by coders with no functional programming background.

Another way to put it, without involving side-effects terminology would be:

- use `do-end` for blocks that **perform**
- use `{` and `}` for blocks that **return**

Here are couple of articles with more info:

http://onestepback.org/index.cgi/Tech/Ruby/BraceVsDoEnd.rdoc

http://talklikeaduck.denhaven2.com/2007/10/02/ruby-blocks-do-or-brace

Comment: I think raganwald proposed also this (or something very similar). As it happens, I usually like his ideas a lot, expect for this one :-) multi-line blocks with { } simply look awful...

Comment: @Matt: Haha, no, Ruby is as FP as I've got so far. But I understand the power of it and the significance it is gaining with distributed and parallel computing, however, at least in my environment, people are coming mostly from OO and imperative languages and have no FP training at all.

Comment: @Mladen Great articles. Thanks a lot. I'll try to keep this in mind.

Comment: I need to ask one day the benefits of avoiding side-effects in Ruby. I think it's a good idea, but I could be just following the latest fads.

Comment: @Andrew Grimm: The whole functional purity thing probably came before programming languages (most FP concepts like that have their roots in math). Definitely pre-dates OO, I think its safe to say its not a fad.

Comment: @Mladen: yeah, I came to FP from ruby too. A coworker (now a friend) basically considered introducing variables a personal failure, and would write his code by chaining functions together and abusing data structures, rather then reaching for iteration and variables first like most people do. Everyone at work called him the "one line wonder", but I thought it was some of the most elegant coding style I had ever seen. Now I am a lisp nut (on my free time), and write ruby and javascript about as close to lisp as I can make them (without implementing a s-exp parser)

Comment: @Andrew: There's no immediate benefit (save for readability and elegance, which is somewhat subjective), but in the long run, it's good to be aware - perhaps another Ruby interpreter will emerge that will know how to make use of purely functional blocks, or we'll be migrating our code to another language and thinking in advance would save us some work. Of course, we shouldn't force FP style where another approach is more elegant.

Comment: Wouldn't the {} require less memory?  It seems to me that the tight binding requires less work on the stack, because of how the data is moved around... I could be wrong but that's what it looked like when I read the libs...

Comment: No, they are equivalent.

Answer (score 10):

Idiomatic ruby is

```
method_name {|param| param.do_something} # squigglies for one liners

# do/end for multi-line
method_name do |param|
  param.do_something
end
```

One reason for this is for chaining, `foo.map {|f| f.num}.reduce(0) {|memo, i| memo + i}` looks nicer then hanging a method call off of an `end` like

```
foo.map do |f| 
  f.num
end.reduce(0) do |memo, i| 
  memo + i
end
```

There is just something strange about calling a method off of `end`, even though syntactically the two are equivalent.

Comment: I see what you mean about hanging a method call off an end... that does look odd.

Thanks for the insight.

Comment: @Matt Briggs, why do you think `do .. end` requires more semicolons than `{ .. }`?

Comment: @DigitalRoss: I just tried it, and you are right, it doesn't need them. I had assumed it was like doing a one line `def`, where the end needs to be on its own line, or you need to end your statement with a semicolon. correcting the answer.

Comment: @kivetros: some times doing one liners do. for example, `def foo 'foo'; end` or `class Foo; end` or `if cond? then 'foo'; end`. I just always assumed do/end was the same deal.

Answer (score 4):

The usual convention is `{ ... }` blocks for one-liners and `do ... end` for multi-liners. I generally follow this convention but should I ever be king I think I would use `do .. end` more often.

An occasional issue with `{}` is that `{}` binds more tightly than `do end` so the *only* way to write a poetry-mode block for a method that also has parameters is to use `do end`, otherwise the block will be part of the parameter and will not be not passed directly to the method.

```
def f x
  yield x
end

f 123 do |n| p n end  # works
f 123  { |n| p n }    # does not work
f(123) { |n| p n }    # works, of course
```

Of course, if you *wanted* to attach a block to a parameter in poetry mode, then you win with `{}` followed by `do end`.

```
def g  ; p ['g', yield] end
def f x; p ['f', yield] end

f g { 2 } do 3 end
["g", 2]
["f", 3]
```

Finally, and contrary to some of the advice you have received here, a `;` is *not* needed before `end`.

Comment: Poetry mode? Elaborate, please.

Comment: @kivetros, "poetry mode" refers to wrting Ruby without using `( ... )` around method call parameters. It's a common pattern with DSL code like Rails, but somewhat rare in straight ruby. One problem is that it doesn't always work, important things like chaining do require the parens or the dot will bind to whatever the last parameter expression term was. I wish there was a very low-priority terminal that meant the same thing as `.`.

Comment: i didn't know there was a difference in precidence, but that makes sense due to the differences in and/or vs &&/||. voting this up

Comment: +1 for pointing out the difference in precedence. It's a pain to debug when that one bites us.

Answer (score -2):

"The Ruby way" doesn't advocate any specific style. If they didn't want you to have the option to use curly braces, it wouldn't be in the language. That said, conform to your team's coding style (if you're working with a team).

Most Ruby code I've seen uses `end` in place of curly braces, but I don't use Ruby so I can't say for sure that this is the preferred style. Ruby has more than one way of doing things -- you can use whichever way pleases you (within reason).

Comment: When you say "The Ruby way", are you talking about the book, or in general?

Comment: @Andrew I wasn't even aware of the book. I was just speaking based on my knowledge of Ruby's design philosophy and Rubyist attitudes.

Comment: yeah, that's what I was asking about... the design philosophy and attitudes.